# Write to parameter value in Adaxes PowerShell action

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This is a question about using PowerShell with Custom Commands (or scheduled tasks) in the Adaxes Active Directory management software by Softerra.

I am trying to accept a parameter from a user when using a custom command, then I need to take that value and modify it for use in a future action of the custom command.

A "for example" use-case would be creating a script that sets a user's out of office, where the custom command takes a target user reference in the out of office message.  The first action in the custom command would find the email address of the provided user, then the second action would set the out-of-office with a message telling recipients for immediate assistance to email the provided user's email address.  I realize there may be ways to solve this with one PowerShell script, but there are MANY scenarios where it would be beneficial to process provided information with a script action for use with MULTIPLE future actions in the custom command.

I already know how to access parameter values in custom commands for Softerra Adaxes, but I can't figure out how to WRITE to parameter values.

Accessing values:

```
 $context.GetParameterValue('param-Example')
```

Does anyone know how to write TO parameter values?  `$context.SetParameterValue()` does not work.  This would be extremely useful for being able to store and manipulate values between actions in custom commands in Adaxes.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for something similar, the answer I got from Adaxes support was that there is no means to do this currently with their software.

The only work-around would be writing to a property of the object being modified, then reference that property later.

For instance, writing a value to the extensionAttribute1 property of a user, then referencing that later in the script in a different action.

If anyone comes up with a better solution or Adaxes changes this, please feel free to suggest a better solution!